# Cambiar el elemento seleccionado en un menú Drop-Down

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy utilizando dos menús desplegables de los especificados en [material-components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Menu.md#exposed-dropdown-menus) para un rango de precio, uno para el precio mínimo y otro para el máximo. Estoy usando este listener para obtener el Item seleccionado: (minPrice y maxPrice son TextInputLayout)

```
(minPrice.editText as AutoCompleteTextView).onItemClickListener =
    OnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, position, id ->
        val selectedValue: String? = adapter.getItem(position)
    }

(maxPrice.editText as AutoCompleteTextView).onItemClickListener =
    OnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, position, id ->
        val selectedValue: String? = adapter2.getItem(position)
    }
```

Pero también quiero que, por ejemplo, si el usuario ha seleccionado 15.000€ para el mínimo, entonces si el usuario selecciona 7.000€ como máximo, cambiarlo automáticamente por el mínimo (en este caso 15.000€), así el rango no se queda negativo.

El problema es que no sé cómo cambiar el valor seleccionado en el drop-down. He intentado hacer esto: (priceMaxItems es la lista de precios)

```
if(priceMaxItems[maxPrice.editText?.text.toString()]!! priceMinItems[minPrice.editText?.text.toString()]!!) {
    maxPrice.editText?.text  = minPrice.editText?.text
}
```

El problema de esto es que entonces [desaparecen todos los otros precios de la lista](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDUqQ.png). Cómo hago para que siga igual la lista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es normal que desaparezcan las demás sugerencias ya que la función de un `AutoCompleteTextView` es mostrar sólo las opciones que coincidan con lo que escribiste. Para cambiar ese comportamiento existe un método [setText](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView#settext) con un segundo parámetro para especificar si quieres filtrar las opciones o no. En tu caso debes pasarle `false`

```
maxPrice.editText?.setText(minPrice.editText?.text, false)
```

Si declaraste `editText` con un tipo distinto a `AutoCompleteTextView` tendrás que hacer un cast

```
(maxPrice.editText as? AutoCompleteTextView)?.setText(minPrice.editText?.text, false)
```

De todos modos deberías considerar usar otra implementación del material dropdown menu porque esa basada en AutoCompleteTextView puede causarte muchos [problemas](https://blog.usejournal.com/there-is-no-material-design-spinner-for-android-3261b7c77da8). Afortunadamente hay una [nueva implementación](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#dropdownmenu), incluida en la librería [jetpack compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose), que es más fácil de usar y no requiere xml.